# How variables are declared in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I guess something is wrong with this I believe. I have an array of data set I'm trying to perform some analysis on. This is what I want to do. Say for example the following is the array

`signal=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1...]`, I want to take the data points `0:3` stored somewhere, I need them and also replace those `0:3` with zeros. This is how I did it but the final result comes out right but the stored `0:3` data points stored also come out to be zeros. Can anyone help me out here. I thought it was something simple to do but I have been battling with this for the past couple of days. Thanks in advance!

here is my code:

```
n = len(signal)

for i in range(n):

    first_3points = signal[0:3]

    signal[0:3] = 0

    trancated_signal = signal
```

I will be very glad to see where I went wrong!

Comment: I don't see what the title of this question has to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: What is the loop for? Do you want overlapping or separate samples of length three? Or just the first three? The minimal fix could be `signal[:3] = [0, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your application is better served with numpy, which is well-developed to work with arrays representing signal samples.  You may already be using numpy, since if `signal` is a list, the assignment `signal[0:3] = 0` raises a `TypeError`.  Here's how I'd do it using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
N = 256
signal = np.ones(N)
first3 = signal[0:3].copy()
signal[0:3] = 0
```

Note that if you don't make `first3` a copy of the first elements in `signal`, it just becomes a view into `signal`, and when you change elements in `signal`, you also change `first3`.  If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to save the original elements from `signal` in `first3` before you change them.

Comment: frank128791, excellent it worked thanks a lot for your help. Yes I was to store that and make changes

Answer (score 1):

Using ordinary lists instead of numpy this is quite simple:

```
signal = [1] * 20
first_3_points = signal[:3]
signal[:3] = [0] * 3
```

The loop in your original code appears to be unnecessary.